# With Omega, how to inline branding zone with header zone

Tags: 7, theming

I want set my branding (logo) zone to 4 cols to the left, and the header zone (8 cols) with the two header regions, inline to the right.

Do I simply do this in CSS? Do I specify the branding and header zone wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use 1 of the zones, not both. Either move the header regions to the branding zone, or move the branding zone to the header region.
Think of it as zones being vertical and regions being horizontal, if you want some regions inline, they should be in the same zone.

Comment: Do I specify those in the info file?